# How can I toggle a Go package for community and commercial versions of a project?

Tags: go, open-source

I have written a Go 1.19.5 project with child packages, one of which I'd like to swap out for a different implementation in certain circumstances.

- I am the copyright holder of the project
- The project is 3-Clause BSD; it can be w/e I want it is new
- I have an interface for the package in question

I could do something simple like fork the project as a private repo and change the `import` to a module only in this repo, but the issues there are:

1. The license
2. Is that the easiest way to do this?

There is this plugin package, but I don't know that it solves my problem.

If this ends up more of a licensing issue, and less of a Go question, I can take it to opensource.stackexchange.

Comment: There's no real way to have both versions available in the same codebase, since you don't want some of those changes visible in the public codebase. Most cases of this I've seen keep an internal fork for commercial use, with the commercial changes sufficiently segregated so that they can be continually rebased on the OSS version (or vise versa if you want the commercial version to be the development base, but that risks a higher chance of commercial features leaking out)